# How to hange country of pyecharts 3D bar Charts (China map default)?

Tags: python, 3d, bar-chart

Is there a way to generate a 3D bar chart on a map using another country map, other than China?

This is the default chart, i dont see where to change the map, please advise.
I can change the coordinates of bars but not the default map.

```
from pyecharts import options as opts
from pyecharts.charts import Map3D
from pyecharts.globals import ChartType
from pyecharts.commons.utils import JsCode

example_data = [
    ("黑龙江", [127.9688, 45.368, 100]),
    ("内蒙古", [110.3467, 41.4899, 300]),
    ("吉林", [125.8154, 44.2584, 300]),
    ("辽宁", [123.1238, 42.1216, 300]),
    ("河北", [114.4995, 38.1006, 300]),
    ("天津", [117.4219, 39.4189, 300]),


]

c = (
    Map3D()
    .add_schema(
        itemstyle_opts=opts.ItemStyleOpts(
            color="rgb(5,101,123)",
            opacity=1,
            border_width=0.8,
            border_color="rgb(62,215,213)",
        ),
        map3d_label=opts.Map3DLabelOpts(
            is_show=False,
            formatter=JsCode("function(data){return data.name + " " + data.value[2];}"),
        ),
        emphasis_label_opts=opts.LabelOpts(
            is_show=False,
            color="#fff",
            font_size=10,
            background_color="rgba(0,23,11,0)",
        ),
        light_opts=opts.Map3DLightOpts(
            main_color="#fff",
            main_intensity=1.2,
            main_shadow_quality="high",
            is_main_shadow=False,
            main_beta=10,
            ambient_intensity=0.3,
        ),
    )
    .add(
        series_name="bar3D",
        data_pair=example_data,
        type_=ChartType.BAR3D,
        bar_size=1,
        shading="lambert",
        label_opts=opts.LabelOpts(
            is_show=False,
            formatter=JsCode("function(data){return data.name + ' ' + data.value[2];}"),
        ),
    )
    .set_global_opts(title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title="Map3D-Bar3D"))
    .render("map3d_with_bar3d.html")
)
```